# Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to create vendor registration from for our vendor. How to create Form helper in custom form

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
<ul>
<li class="fields">

                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

I m getting error Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object I need to know how can i crete form object in magento...

Answer (score 0):

In this case `getFormData()` just returns the Model or Helper which owns the function `getEmail()`

So just create a Block class with the function `getFormData()` and create a Helper class which owns the `getEmail()` function.

HTH